# Single database connection for application

Tags: database

My collegue is defending that opening a single database connection for an application is much better and faster than opening and closing it using a pool.

He has an ApplicationStart method where he inits `Application('db')` and keeps this connection live across the app. This app is mostly contains readonly data.

How can I persuade him?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends a lot on what the "application" here is. If this is a client application that works on a single thread and does things sequentially, then frankly there won't be any noticeable difference either way. In that scenario, if you use the pool it will basically be a pool of 1 item, and opening a connection from the pool will be virtually instantaneous (and certainly not noticeable compared to network IO). In that scenario I would *still* say use the inbuilt pooling, as it will avoid assumptions when you change scenario.

However, if you application uses more than one thread, or via any other mechanism does more than one thing at a time (`async`) etc, using a single connection would be very bad; either it will outright *fail*, or you will need to synchronize around the connection, which would limit you severely. Note that any server-side application (any kind of web application, WCF service, SOAP service, or socket service) would react very badly to his idea.

Perhaps the main way to convince him is simply: ask him to prove it. Ask for a repeatable test / demonstration that shows this difference.